# What are the difference between IDXGIFactory and other IDXGIFactory version?

Tags: directx, dxgi

I want to know the difference of the IDXGIFactory1, IDXGIFactory2 and so on. What can that difference give Benefits to  DirectX11 or DirectX12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IDXGIFactory1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nn-dxgi-idxgifactory1) adds DXGI 1.1 support to the application, which is available on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, and as an update to Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2008. [DXGI 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#dxgi-11-changes) provides new functionality like Synchronized Shared Surfaces Support, BGRA etc.

[IDXGIFactory2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nn-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2) adds [DXGI 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#dxgi-12-changes) support and includes methods to create a newer version swap chain [IDXGISwapChain1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nn-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1) with more features than [IDXGISwapChain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nn-dxgi-idxgiswapchain) and to monitor stereoscopic 3D capabilities.

Comment: If you want to support DirectX 11.0, you should use ``IDXGIFactory1``. If you assume DirectX 11.1 or better (Windows 7 SP 1 with KB2670838, Windows 8+), then you should use ``IDXGIFactory2``. If you require DirectX 12, use ``IDXGIFactory4``.

Comment: and now I want to ask is that what are the difference between EnumAdapter and EnumAdapter1?

Comment: You have to use EnumAdapters1 with DXGI 1.1 (targeting DirectX 11.1).

Comment: but I found that I can use EnumAdapter get the same result as using EnumAdapter1.